# Generating E-Commerce Information Via C# within Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, sitefinity

I need to know how to get the properties in a Javascript code to generate based on what is in a shopping cart on a Sitefinity (C#) built site.

I know what the code looks like for adding a transaction to GA, but I don't know how to get the code to generate based on what is in the cart. I know how to the information to generate within an HTML environment but how do you do so within a Javascript one?

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '1234',
'name': 'Fresh Egg',
'category': 'Blue eggs',
'quantity':'2',
'revenue': '43.66',
'shipping': '3',
'tax': '1.29'
});
```

How do I get the ID, name, etc. to generate based on what is in the cart? Not pulling the information out of the cart (user-side) but rather out of the same place that is generating the cart information (server-side).

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please show what relevant code you currently have for reference in the question as a formatted code block. Replace the link to the image with a formatted code block.

Comment: It has been switched out.

Comment: You will need a custom widget that uses the Sitefinity eCommerce API to get the data from the shopping cart and then generate the js code you need. 
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-query-cart-orders is a good starting point